# SSD1306 horizontal mode not working

Tags: embedded, display, oled, ssd1306

I'm trying to fill the screen of SSD1306 white. I'm using horizontal page addressing mode to not set page address manually using commands. According to [SSD1306 datasheet](https://cdn-shop.adafruit.com/datasheets/SSD1306.pdf), when the column address pointer reaches column end address, the address page address pointer is increased by 1. But for some reasons in my case page address pointer isn't increasing for some reasons. Also will be grateful for examples of using horizontal page addressing from some open-source drivers if someone has them.

Here is the pseudocode:

```c
display_write_command(0xAF); // Display ON

display_write_command(0x20); // Set Page Addressing Mode
display_write_command(0x00); // Horizontal Addressing Mode

display_write_command(0x21); // Set Start and End Column Addresses
display_write_command(0);    // Start Column Address = 0
display_write_command(127); // End Column Address = 127

display_write_command(0x22); // Set Start and End Page Addresses
display_write_command(0);   // Start Page Address = 0
display_write_command(7);     // End Page Address = 7

for (int i = 0; i < 1024; i++) { 
    display_write_data(0xFF);   // 0xFF one filled column
    Delay(50); // A little bit delay for showcase
}
```

Here is showcase video: [Showcase Link](https://files.fm/f/8um4ts2jrp)
(Sorry for link, unfortunately StackExchange doesn't support video in posts.)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @Community It could be clarified, but this question does make sense if you’ve ever developed these types of drivers.

Comment: Can you show the documentation that shows that this increments? In the drivers I’ve been involved with I’m pretty sure you have to manually set the page.

Comment: @ErikFriesen https://cdn-shop.adafruit.com/datasheets/SSD1306.pdf Page 35. Horizontal addressing mode

Comment: Did you send the rest of the init code as shown in page 5 of the datasheet?

Comment: This is probably your answer here.  https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/491830/ssd1306-128x32-oled-initialization-problem

Comment: TLDR you are probably presently sending one byte commands instead of command “strings” with one cs low high